# what is the difference between java object (how it is represented in memory) and spark SQL object?

Tags: apache-spark

I have read in many articles and in the "SparK: The definitive guide book" that the spark-SQL structured data representation (at low level) is not the same as java objects.

A line in the book goes below...

"Beginning with Spark 1.0, the project added Spark SQL, a new API for working with structured data - tables with structured data format that is not tied to Java's in-memory representation."

If the low level Java object representation is different than the default representation by JRE, then how the JRE can correctly read/write objects ?

Can some one please help me to understand this.

Thanks!

I am unable to find any articles related to this.

Answer (score 0):

"Beginning with Spark 1.0, the project added Spark SQL, a new API for working with structured data - tables with structured data format that is not tied to Java's in-memory representation." -> This is Dataset or Row objects

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.html

It mean its not custom java object,rather its a spark type object.

You can also create custom java objects in spark using rdd and spark-sql as well.

Also i advice to go through https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html and not look at spark 1.0